# Maven: Module dependency not resolved

Tags: java, maven

I'm running against an issue related with local dependency module.

I'm very exhausted. I don't quite figure out what's wrong!

I have a parent `pom.xml` with these two modules:

```
<modules>
    <module>rep-digital-common</module>
    <module>rep-digital-api</module>
</modules>
```

parent `pom.xml` file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>net.gencat.transversal.repositori.digital</groupId>
    <artifactId>rep-digital</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <!-- Inherit defaults from Spring Boot -->
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <modules>
        <module>rep-digital-common</module>
        <module>rep-digital-api</module>
    </modules>

    <properties>
        <spring-cloud.version>Finchley.RELEASE</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>net.gencat.transversal.repositori.digital</groupId>
                <artifactId>rep-digital-common</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

First, I install locally the first one:

```
$ mvn -pl rep-digital-common clean package install -U
--- maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install (default-install) @ rep-digital-common ---
[INFO] Installing /home/jcabre/projectes/repo-digital/rep-digital-common/target/rep-digital-common-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar to /home/jcabre/.m2/repository/net/gencat/transversal/espaidoc/rep-digital-common/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/rep-digital-common-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Installing /home/jcabre/projectes/repo-digital/rep-digital-common/pom.xml to /home/jcabre/.m2/repository/net/gencat/transversal/espaidoc/rep-digital-common/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/rep-digital-common-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Once `rep-digital-common` is installed locally, I'm trying to compile the other module:

> Failed to read artifact descriptor for net.gencat.transversal.espaidoc:rep-digital-common:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact net.gencat.transversal.espaidoc:rep-digital:pom:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT

I've checked local repository content:

```
➜  ls ~/.m2/repository/net/gencat/transversal/espaidoc/rep-digital-common
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT  maven-metadata-local.xml
```

Looking at exception meesage:

```
-> Caused by: org.apache.maven.project.DependencyResolutionException: Could not resolve dependencies for project net.gencat.transversal.espaidoc:rep-digital-api:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at net.gencat.transversal.espaidoc:rep-digital-common:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
-> Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for net.gencat.transversal.espaidoc:rep-digital-common:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
-> Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactNotFoundException: Could not find artifact net.gencat.transversal.espaidoc:rep-digital:pom:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
```

Any ideas?

`rep-digital-api pom.xml`:

```
<project ...>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>net.gencat.transversal.espaidoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>rep-digital</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>rep-digital-api</artifactId>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring Boot -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.gencat.transversal.espaidoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>rep-digital-common</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Complete exception message:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project rep-digital-api: Could not resolve dependencies for project net.gencat.transversal.espaidoc:rep-digital-api:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at net.gencat.transversal.espaidoc:rep-digital-common:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to read artifact descriptor for net.gencat.transversal.espaidoc:rep-digital-common:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact net.gencat.transversal.espaidoc:rep-digital:pom:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal on project rep-digital-api: Could not resolve dependencies for project net.gencat.transversal.espaidoc:rep-digital-api:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at net.gencat.transversal.espaidoc:rep-digital-common:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDependencies (LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:249)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.resolveProjectDependencies (LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.ensureDependenciesAreResolved (MojoExecutor.java:246)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:200)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:194)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:955)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.project.DependencyResolutionException: Could not resolve dependencies for project net.gencat.transversal.espaidoc:rep-digital-api:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at net.gencat.transversal.espaidoc:rep-digital-common:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve (DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:178)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDependencies (LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:223)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.resolveProjectDependencies (LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.ensureDependenciesAreResolved (MojoExecutor.java:246)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:200)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:194)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:955)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.collection.DependencyCollectionException: Failed to collect dependencies at net.gencat.transversal.espaidoc:rep-digital-common:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.collectDependencies (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:293)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.collectDependencies (DefaultRepositorySystem.java:282)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve (DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:169)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDependencies (LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:223)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.resolveProjectDependencies (LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.ensureDependenciesAreResolved (MojoExecutor.java:246)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:200)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:194)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:955)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for net.gencat.transversal.espaidoc:rep-digital-common:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom (DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:323)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor (DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:192)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.resolveCachedArtifactDescriptor (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:539)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.getArtifactDescriptorResult (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:524)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:365)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.process (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.collectDependencies (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:256)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.collectDependencies (DefaultRepositorySystem.java:282)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve (DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:169)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDependencies (LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:223)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.resolveProjectDependencies (LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.ensureDependenciesAreResolved (MojoExecutor.java:246)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:200)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:194)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:955)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.model.resolution.UnresolvableModelException: Could not find artifact net.gencat.transversal.espaidoc:rep-digital:pom:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultModelResolver.resolveModel (DefaultModelResolver.java:178)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultModelResolver.resolveModel (DefaultModelResolver.java:224)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.readParentExternally (DefaultModelBuilder.java:1051)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.readParent (DefaultModelBuilder.java:829)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build (DefaultModelBuilder.java:331)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom (DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:314)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor (DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:192)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.resolveCachedArtifactDescriptor (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:539)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.getArtifactDescriptorResult (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:524)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:365)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.process (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.collectDependencies (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:256)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.collectDependencies (DefaultRepositorySystem.java:282)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve (DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:169)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDependencies (LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:223)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.resolveProjectDependencies (LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.ensureDependenciesAreResolved (MojoExecutor.java:246)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:200)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:194)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:955)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not find artifact net.gencat.transversal.espaidoc:rep-digital:pom:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:422)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:224)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:201)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultModelResolver.resolveModel (DefaultModelResolver.java:174)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultModelResolver.resolveModel (DefaultModelResolver.java:224)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.readParentExternally (DefaultModelBuilder.java:1051)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.readParent (DefaultModelBuilder.java:829)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build (DefaultModelBuilder.java:331)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom (DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:314)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor (DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:192)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.resolveCachedArtifactDescriptor (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:539)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.getArtifactDescriptorResult (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:524)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:365)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.process (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.collectDependencies (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:256)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.collectDependencies (DefaultRepositorySystem.java:282)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve (DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:169)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDependencies (LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:223)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.resolveProjectDependencies (LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.ensureDependenciesAreResolved (MojoExecutor.java:246)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:200)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:194)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:955)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactNotFoundException: Could not find artifact net.gencat.transversal.espaidoc:rep-digital:pom:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:224)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:201)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultModelResolver.resolveModel (DefaultModelResolver.java:174)
    at...
```

**EDIT**

I've tried to remove `rep-digital-common` from `dependencyManagement`, and I've added version artifact field on `rep-digital-api` pom.xml.

`rep-digital-api` module `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.gencat.transversal.espaidoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>rep-digital-common</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

parent `pom.xml` `dependencyManagement` section:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

It's really strange since if I execute `mvn clean compile` everything works. However, if I perform `mvn -pl repdigital-api clean compile` it doesn't work.

Another thing is struggling me is why in the message it's telling me that:

> Could not find artifact net.gencat.transversal.espaidoc:rep-digital:pom:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT

So, why `rep-digital:pom` could not be found?

Answer (score 0):

In your child pom change to

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.gencat.transversal.espaidoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>rep-digital-common</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Then take it out of the entire dependencyManagement from the parent pom.